# How do I bypass XSS filter from Web.xml and add another filter to modify the request and forward it?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I already have a 3rd party application on tomcat which has XSS filter, when I add my filter and filter mapping the application does not work while trying to send the request.

```
<filter>

<filter-name>XSS</filter-name>

<filter-class>de.gauss.vip.contentexplorer.servlet.CrossScriptingFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>XSS</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
```

I tried adding my code before/after the filter but it is not working, how do I add a filter to existing web.xml and still forward the request to correct server. Below is the filter code :

```
    @WebFilter("/SecondFilter")
public class SecondFilter implements Filter {
    public String decryptedString;
    private static final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    public String globalKey;
    public String RedirectURL;
    public String DN;
    public String TYPE;
    public String NAME;
    public String NUMBER;
    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */

     @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         //chain.doFilter(req, res);    
         HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();//contentexpplre
            System.out.println("reuqestURI :"+requestURI); ///contentexplorer/servlet/VipDms/SSNdecrypt
            String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString() +"?"+request.getQueryString();
            System.out.println("URL :"+url);

            if(url.contains("/VipDms"))
            {
                    String toReplace =url.substring(118);//79 for localhost
                //String toReplace = requestURI.substring(32,42);
                    System.out.println("toReplace :"+toReplace);
                    String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
                    System.out.println("queryString :"+queryString);

                    if (queryString!=null) {

                        //NUMBER = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("NUMBER");
                        System.out.println("Number parameter :"+toReplace);
                        DN = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("DN");
                        TYPE = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("TYPE");
                        NAME = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("NAME");
                      //NUMBER = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("NUMBER");

                        if(toReplace!=null){

                            //Code to load key from property file
                            try {

                                String filename = "Secretkey.properties";
                                input = SecondFilter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                                    if(input==null){
                                        System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find :" + filename);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                prop.load(input);
                                globalKey=prop.getProperty("Secretkey");
                                System.out.println("Global Key : "+globalKey);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                            //Key loaded in code 

                            byte[] clearText;
                            try {
                                clearText = AesEncryption.decryptBase64EncodedWithManagedIV(toReplace, globalKey);
                                decryptedString = new String(clearText,characterEncoding);
                                System.out.println("ClearText :" +decryptedString);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //code ends to decrypt the SSN
                            //String newquerystring = "-NUMBER="+decryptedString;
                            //change the URL query string
                            String URL1 = url.replace(toReplace, decryptedString);
                            System.out.println("URL1 :"+URL1);
                            URL1 = "/servlet/VipDms?DN=Docview_Test&TYPE=OL&NAME=OLDNEW_GUL&-NUMBER=123456789";
                            req.getRequestDispatcher(URL1).forward(req, res);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                             chain.doFilter(req, res);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                         chain.doFilter(req, res);
                    }

                    //Decrypt SSN
              /**      if (queryString!=null) {

                    //decryption completed and stored in decryptedString variable

                   /**System.out.println("queryString :"+queryString);
                    System.out.println("DN : "+DN);
                    System.out.println("TYPE : "+TYPE);
                    System.out.println("NAME : "+NAME);
                    System.out.println("S1/ NUMBER : "+NUMBER);
                    System.out.println("decrypted S1/ Number : "+decryptedString);
                   String newQuerystring = "VipDms?DN="+DN+"&TYPE="+TYPE+"&NAME="+NAME+"&-NUMBER="+decryptedString;
                  String URL1 = requestURI.replace(toReplace, newQuerystring);
                  System.out.println("URL1--"+URL1);
                    String decryptedQueryString = "/servlet/VipDms?DN="+DN+"&TYPE="+TYPE+"&NAME="+NAME+"&-NUMBER="+decryptedString;
                    System.out.println("decrypted string--"+decryptedQueryString);
                    // HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                  //resp.sendRedirect(Redirect);
                    req.getRequestDispatcher(decryptedQueryString).forward(req, res);  

            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }**/
            }
            }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: please clarify which requests(url pattern) should go to which filters. CrossScriptingFilter and SecondFilter or just SecondFilter. And what is happing with the current configuration.

Comment: so there is no different URL pattern that should go, I am just modifying the last request parameter from the request and forwarding it. Is there a way I can use requestwrapper and do chainfilter?